# Mysql load data infile wrong path

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I badly need you help.

Error showing after importing .CSV file using mysql load data infile.

I have a form upload below which working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
```

and a PHP upload script using load data infile.

```
require("../config/conn.php");


  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['my-file']['error']==0) {
    $path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/dom/test/uploads/' . $_FILES['my-file']['name'];
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {

        echo $mysql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$_FILES['my-file']['name']."' 
                REPLACE INTO TABLE table 
                FIELDS 
                    TERMINATED BY ',' 
                LINES 
                    TERMINATED BY '\\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES 
                (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`....)";

                $query = mysqli_query($link, $mysql) or die(mysqli_error($link));

if(!$query) 
{
    printf("Error message: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));     
}   




      } else {
        echo "The file was not uploaded successfully.";
      }
    } else {
      echo "File already exists. Please upload another file.";
    }
  } else {
    echo "The file was not uploaded successfully.";
    echo "(Error Code:" . $_FILES['my-file']['error'] . ")";
  }
```

Everything is fine, except the load data local infile cannot see the right path. please see the error: **Can't find file 'logJan262013.CSV'.** but the .csv file is uploaded successfully in folder 'uploads/'. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks alot!

Comment: Use a full path, not just the file name.

Comment: just because you moved the file to that uploads folder doesn't mean mysql will actually look for it there. You're also opening your server to a total remote compromise with this code (NEVER use user-provided `['name']` directly in filesystem operations).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the query:

```
$mysql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$_FILES['my-file']['name']."'...
```

I do believe you are wishing to use the full path

```
$mysql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$path."'...
```

Answer (score 0):

You do

```
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['my-file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
```

before

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, $mysql)
```

So, it is not surprising, that `LOAD DATA` doesn't find the file.

If you give `LOAD DATA` the proper `$path`, it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Err you haven't told the LOAD DATA INFILE the path! Try telling it the path and all should be OK.